# ANTLR4 Hangs Up When Dealing with EOF

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've a simple ANTLR4 grammar :

```
grammar Test;
preprocessing_file: oneline+;

oneline: IDENTIFIER? new_line;

new_line: EOF|CRLF
;

WS: [ \t\f]+ -> channel(2);

CRLF: '\r'? '\n';


IDENTIFIER:  (NONDIGIT | DIGIT )+
; 
  fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
  fragment NONDIGIT: [_a-zA-Z]  ;
```

I was testing how to use a newline rule that allows the last line not being terminated by a CRLF. I tested the grammar with ANTLR v4.1 and v4.5.3.

An input file of a few lines of text caused ANTLR4 to freeze and OutOfMemoryException after a while. It looks like ANTLR4 entered some infinite loop. Is it a bug with ANTLR4? Did I do anything wrong? Also, if I remove the `EOF` in `new_line` rule, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to add an `EOF` to the main rule. Without it, the main rule will never terminate - the lexer will continue to produce `EOF` tokens that are successfully consumed by the `new_line` rule.

```
preprocessing_file: oneline+? EOF ;
oneline: IDENTIFIER? new_line ;
new_line: EOF|CRLF ;
```

Comment: Thx, that's the problem. I didn't realize there could be infinitely many EOF produced by the lexer if we keep consuming it.  But the solution you suggested won't work. The real culprit is that the 'oneline' rule could match a single EOF indefinitely which the lexer also keeps pumping out indefinitely. Need to use a non-greedy operator i.e. oneline+? in addition to the extra EOF

Answer (score 1):

EOF [end of file] should not be in new_line rule. Just change

```
oneline: IDENTIFIER? new_line
```

into

```
oneline: IDENTIFIER? new_line?
```

validate the presence of new_line in later phases if needed to validate at all

Comment: (1) why EOF is not allowed in a rule? isn't it created for us to explicitly match the end of file
(2) in this grammar IDENTIFIER can be anything, but my real grammar is very specific about the content and dictate a new_line must be following it. So new_line cannot be optional here. Anyway, there is no reason for ANLTR4 to hang and throw OutOfMemoryException later

Comment: I am not saying it is not allowed, only that there is no real reason to put it there. put in the root rule at the end and see if it helps, if not, there must be another mistake... i am not seeing any in the grammar / is it the whole grammar?

Comment: yes the whole grammar, I just excluded  the 'grammar xx'; line. (I just edited the src to include that line). And, without the EOF in the new_line rule, ANTLR4 works correctly but cannot match my last line having no trailing CRLF